# Which caching method is better in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, object-cache, output-cache

I am looking at available options for caching in SharePoint 2016 for sites with lots of css,  js, images etc in master page and page lay out and have few question around it. There are three types of caching is available I am looking at and wondering which one is better ? Please share your experience if you have seen one better then other.

At TechNet article  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229(v=office.16).aspx you will see three type of caching.

•Configuring BLOB cache settings
•Configuring page output cache profile settings
•Configuring object cache settings

Object caching is not for css, js or blobs but wondering if configuring all three will cause any issues or degrade performance . Thoughts ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implement the Object cache and Blob caches, we see the improvement in the performance. it depends upon the one's situation, every cache settings have plus and minuses.

**Object Cache:** if you are using the publishing infrastructure feature then this cache will help you to increase the performance. Object cache stores the objects (List, library, pagelayouts etc) in WFE's memory, which help to reduce the traffic between from WFE to SQL server. I would recommend this for better performance.

**Blob Cache:** as you are looking to cache the css / js files then blob cache is best option. In BLOB cache, items are store on the disks of WFE, SharePoint pick the item from WFE and render them quickly as compare to make a trip to SQL and bring the data back.

I never used the Output cache so little experience if it really helps or not? mostly what i read avoid it.

[Read this technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I have tested both ( output caching and blob) and have not seen much difference . First hit is always slow as it is building cache and following hits are faster for the time mentioned. With the Blob I see there are more issues if you have 3 or 4 wfe as there is no way to have a synced cache so not sure how big that issue can be if cache life is set to 12 hours.

Comment: my first hit is 8 to 12 seconds and following are 2 to 3 using those caching options , is there a way to improve first hit by using cache or ? I already have wakeup script and application initializer set up.

Comment: i think wakeupscript is the solution, unless someone else know anything. we have wakeupscript in our farm.